# Selling my Used Servers online?

Tags: hp, dell, startup, reseller

I am new here and doing a bit of research.

I am running a startup which takes used technology, fixes it up and sells it online.  I am looking for the best method/place to sell servers online, both new and old. Does such a place exist? Are there differences between corporate and hobbyest? Thanks in advance!

Jes

Comment: eBay, Craigslist, friends, whatever. Totally off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You're late to the game. Ideally you'd have your own retail site, in addition to a presence on eBay. But why would someone buy from *you* when Tier-1 manufacturers already sell refurbished equipment?